# How to select rows based on two column that must contain specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-loc

I have a dataset with a lot of incorrect duplicates on a certain field, in my reproducible example there are duplicates in serial with different color and shape. I have the actual dataframe with the correct color and shape to serial mapped, and need to select the correct rows with that.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

items = pd.DataFrame({
    'serial': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002'],
    'color': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green'],
    'shape': ['Square', 'Circle', 'Star', 'Square', 'Circle', 'Star'],
    'more_data': ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
    'even_more_data': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
})

real = pd.DataFrame({
    'serial': ['0001', '0002'],
    'color': ['Blue', 'Red'],
    'shape': ['Square', 'Circle']
})
```

Then,

```
Out[1]: items
    serial  color   shape   more_data   even_more_data
0   0001    Blue    Square  G           A
1   0001    Red     Circle  H           B
2   0001    Green   Star    I           C
3   0002    Blue    Square  J           D
4   0002    Red     Circle  K           E
5   0002    Green   Star    L           F

Out[2]: real
    serial  color   shape
0   0001    Blue    Square
1   0002    Red     Circle
```

I need to use 'real' to select the correct rows in 'items' so the expected result is:

```
Out[3]: 
    serial  color   shape   more_data   even_more_data
0   0001    Blue    Square  G           A
4   0002    Red     Circle  K           E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merge:

```
real.merge(items)
```

output

```
Out[305]: 
  serial color   shape more_data even_more_data
0   0001  Blue  Square         G              A
1   0002   Red  Circle         K              E
```

Comment: That was more simple than I thought. I guess I was searching up the wrong keywords to find the right answer. Thank you.

Comment: @geistmate glad i could help! if you like the answer check out this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235